# Camera activity in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

When i start recording video using  camera ,it  starts recording , but if i hold the camera idle without doing any operation(like touch , tap..etc) , device went to sleep mode means device locked , then i need to reopen the device.

I need to make the device active while recording and not want to go sleep mode while recording. If any one knows that solution please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the PowerManager service. [Have a look at the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).